# HTML Jquery .toggle not toggling back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col one-whole">
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/central.html">Central Plumping</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/roofing.html">Roof</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/drains.html">Drainage</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <a href="../index.html"><img src="img/title.png"></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="burger-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="toggleburger"><i class="fa fa-bars x3" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="../index.html"><img src="img/title.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="burger">
     <div class="row menu">
        <div class="col one-whole">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a><a href="" id="toggleburger"><i class="fa fa-times x3" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/central.html">Central Plumping</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/roofing.html">Roof</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/drains.html">Drainage</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hello all, currently trying to learn basic JQuery. I have managed to create a simple navigation bar, with responsive burger menu that hides and shows each navigation bar based on screen size. I then created a burger div that is 100% screen size fixed when displayed but is currently set it display:none. Now i have got my toggle working to display it, but when i try to close the menu bar, it doesn't seem to toggle back. Any help would be great thankyou.

My Jquery script is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#toggleburger").click(function(){
            $(".menu").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try putting an alert("testing") or console.log("testing") just before menu toggle statement and see if it fires. Because it may be the case that some other element overlaps with your menu button once it is open and so the click is not actually a click on the menu icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting directed off when I click the element you're trying to tie the `click` event to.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p85kazv0/

I've simply prevented the `a` element you're using from its default action (which is of course to direct someone to another location, dictated by whats in the `href=""`):

```
$("#toggleburger").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".menu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much that seemed to fix the issue. Sorry to bother you but would you mind explaining how? Just for future reference. How does the e.preventDefault relate to the anchor?

Comment: @swiners Sure, the click event/function accepts an argument - `(e)` in my case. JS checks if the default event being actioned by the anchor / `a` element is cancelable. If it is (`href` is indeed cancelable), JS will prevent the default event (ie - the `href`). More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 5):

i guess your problem is that you're using an **anchor** tag with **empty href attribute**.

try chaging in

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggleburger"><i class="fa fa-times x3" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

see example in this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nwLt7p86/)

Comment: shouldn't that result in a page reload instead?

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it, I ended up removing the href in general and going with Davids answer which seemed to fix the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, it should works, as you can see in Fiddle. And i suggest to follow this way instead of preventing default behaviour with javascript, or, even better, you should'nt use anchor tag unless you need to navigate somewhere. Instead you can use pretty much any other tag and add some style like `cursor: pointer`, to get the clickable hand pointer

Comment: @pumpkinzzz - Agree with you on using another element - `<button>` would be better. Disagree with not using preventDefault(), there's plenty of scenarios where its extremely useful.

Comment: @DavidWilkinson sure it is, but when actually needed. not in this scenario, i guess

Answer (score 1):

Reasons for unexpected behaviour:

1. `<a>` has `href` set to some other page. If you have to implement the menu or buttons that are only for in page activity you should set it as `href="#"`. Meaning do not redirect me anywhere just perform the event linked with this action, which in your case is toggling of another div.

While `e.preventDefault()` is a workaround, it is not recommended here as the link is sitting there doing nothing. It would suit more if say you had a form that would submit itself but you wanted to do some processing/sanitation before submitting, thereby overriding default action with your logic.

2. There are two elements with `id=toggleburger`. Keep your `id` unique on one html page. This can give you a lot of pain while debugging.

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0htvz7hz/), I have replaced the hamburger image with text "ToggleBurger".

Answer (score 0):

Set the `href` attribute of the `<a>` element equals to `#`:

```
<li><a href="#" id="toggleburger">
```